# SSRS in Iframe not opening popup

Tags: javascript, iframe, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a SSRS 2008 report. And in a textbox of the report i created a action

```
"javascript:void(alert('test'));"
```

This works perfectly if i run the report seperatly. but if I run the report inside a IFrame of a ASP.NET page, it doesn't work. any idea why it does't work???

Comment: I think this may be due to cross domain, as my report server is differnt and it is inside iframe...Any one has any input for this problem of cross domain ssrs method calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this issue in the past. It had to do with the report rendering type. I'm pretty sure it has to be 'HTML' in order for it to work in iframes.

Comment: Just sent an email to my old client to check how I figured that out, I just don't remember!

Comment: Thanks for your help Dominic..The problem was with the domain name. I added domain name to both the URLs (main url and report url). it's working fine. thanks